# Insert array using codeigniter

Tags: arrays, codeigniter, post

I try to insert multiple arrays into database using codeigniter and ajax. After click the submit, database insert to mysql but all the value is blank. What did I miss?

My view:

```
<input type="hidden" name="iduser[]" id="iduser[]" value="<?php echo $rowmyuser->iduser; ?>"/>
<input type="hidden" name="idproduk[]" id="idproduk[]" value="<?php echo $rowproduk->idproduct; ?>"/>
<input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" name="settarget[]" id="settarget[]"/>
```

Save

My controller:

```
public function inserttarget()
{
   $this->target_m->inserttarget_m();
}
```

My model:

```
function inserttarget_m() {
        $iduser = $this->input->post("iduser");
        $idproduk = $this->input->post("idproduk");
        $settarget = $this->input->post("settarget");

        $temp = count($this->input->post("iduser"));

        $datatarget = array();

        for($i=0; $i < 3; $i++)
        {
        $datatarget[]=array(
        "iduser"=>$iduser[$i],
        "idproduct"=>$idproduk[$i],
        "target"=>$settarget[$i],
        );
    }
    $this->db->insert_batch("tbl_targetsales",$datatarget);
  }
```

The Ajax code:

```
function insert_target() 
{
  var DataString=$("#frm_target").serialize();
  document.getElementById("save_target").innerHTML = "<i class='fa fa-cog fa-spin fa-lg fa-fw'></i> Saving...";
  $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '<?php echo base_url();?>target/inserttarget',
        data: DataString,   
        success: function (data) {
      //jQuery("#attendence_report_holder").html(response);
        swal({              
            text: 'success'
            });
      $("#frm_target")[0].reset();
      document.getElementById("save_target").innerHTML = "<i class='fa fa-save'>&nbsp;&nbsp;</i>Save";
      window.location='<?php echo base_url(); ?>target';
    },
    error:function(data){
        swal({
            text: 'error',
            });
      document.getElementById("save_target").innerHTML = "<i class='fa fa-save'>&nbsp;&nbsp;</i>Save";
    }
  });
}
```

I need advice please, what is the problem in the code. Thanks in advance

Comment: how you print `<?php echo $rowmyuser->iduser; ?>` this values to view ??

Comment: if i print the code, its show value same as it should, so i think the problem not in value, but the problem is value from view not send to model.

Answer (score 0):

first you call wrong the inputs in your html for the inputs name are

```
iduser[]
idproduk[]
settarget[]
```

and in your model you call with, and in the array you make to insert you call different variables that you save it

```
iduser
idproduct
target
```

replace all you madel with (using the correct names from form and variables names)

```
function inserttarget_m() {
        $iduser = $this->input->post("iduser");
        $idproduct = $this->input->post("idproduk");
        $target = $this->input->post("settarget");

        $temp = count($iduser);

        $datatarget = array();

        for($i=0; $i < $temp; $i++){
            $datatarget[] = array(
                                 "iduser"    => $iduser[$i],
                                 "idproduct" => $idproduct[$i],
                                 "target"    => $target[$i],
                              );
    }

    $this->db->insert_batch("tbl_targetsales", $datatarget);
}
```

Comment: i had edit my code but not working, in looping for($i=0; $i < 3; $i++) i change to for($i=0; $i < $temp; $i++), the result is error msg. no database added. so i assume the data from view not sending to model.